# django-pyodbc for Django 1.11

Tags: django-pyodbc

I am currently using Django 1.11.1 and am trying to connect to my iSeries Database using the django-pyodbc engine.  However all the documentation I can find states django-pyodbc is only supported through Django 1.10.  Is there any coding modifications I can make to have it support 1.11?

Answer (score 0):

There are several forks and versions named `django-pyodbc`, however, the best maintained I've found is `django-pyodbc-azure`. It supports Django 1.11 and can be found here:

https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure

I have used it with SQL Server 2005 - 2016 (but never Azure). Good luck!